# MVC 3 ViewBag Lost on Partial View Refresh

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, state

I'm using Ajax to refresh a partial view and find that the ViewBag contents are not available when the controller is invoked to perform the refresh.

Specifically, I place an item in ViewBag.ItemToMonitor.  It is available the first time the partial view is rendered (here I use it in the controller, but I also tried using it in the view).  When the partial view is refreshed via Ajax, the *ViewBag* does not contain anything for *ItemToMonitor*.

How can I make data available upon refresh?

Here's a simple example, based on the MVC 3 project template:

**Index.cshtml**

```
<div>
    Select an item to monitor:

    <ul>
    <li>@Html.ActionLink("One", "Monitor", new { itemToMonitor = "Item One" })</li>
    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Two", "Monitor", new { itemToMonitor = "Item Two" })</li>
    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Three", "Monitor", new { itemToMonitoritem = "Item Three" })</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**Monitor.cshtml**

```
@model string
<script type="text/javascript">
    setInterval(function () {
        $.post('@Url.Action("_MonitorDetails")', function (data) {
            $('#refreshMe').html(data);
        }
    );
    }, 5000);
</script>

<h2>Monitor</h2>

<div>Monitoring @ViewBag.ItemToMonitor</div>
<div id="refreshMe">
@Html.Partial("_MonitorDetails")
</div>
```

**_MonitorDetails.cshtml**

```
@model string

<div style="background-color:Blue; color:White">
This is my partial view to monitor '@Model', updated at @DateTime.Now.ToString("u").
</div>
```

**HomeController.cs**

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    ViewBag.Message = "Welcome to ASP.NET MVC!";

    return View();
}

public ActionResult Monitor(string itemToMonitor)
{
    ViewBag.ItemToMonitor = itemToMonitor;

    return View((object)itemToMonitor);
}

public ActionResult _MonitorDetails()
{
    string itemToMonitor = ViewBag.ItemToMonitor;
    // itemToMonitor is null.  Why?
    return PartialView((object)itemToMonitor);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't think a ViewBag in MVC is like a ViewState in WebForms - it is NOT refilled at every request like the ViewState. You have to set everything in the ViewBag again on the next request.

So you need another solution, either

- pass the itemToMonitor string to Monitor in your ajax request
- save the itemToMonitor in the session and access that in _MonitorDetails

Comment: Passing along itemToMonitor in the Ajax request works.  I'll leave this open a while longer hoping for a simpler approach.

Comment: I have some other options in mind like pre action handlers and that kind of stuff but that will be even more complicated, so I think I mentioned the easiest ways. But I'm happy to see an easier solution as well!

Answer (score 1):

Because you have an ajax call, which is really a new request, try using TempData which is specifically for data between requests.

For example, in my Controller I have something like this:

```
if (TempData.ContainsKey("IsReadOnly"))
{
    TempData["IsReadOnly"] = true;
}
else
{
    TempData.Add("IsReadOnly", true);
}
```

I can get this data in my view like this, which is actually inside an MVC telerik grid:

```
columns.Bound(o => o.OrderOfSignature).Width(50).ReadOnly(TempData["IsReadOnly"].ToString().ToLower() == "true" ? true : false).Title("Order");
```

Comment: `== "true" ? true : false`? Why not just `== "true"`?